# Encrypt and decrypt value by RSA algorithm

Tags: c#, rsa

I created a program for encryption and decryption by RSA. For some numeric values, the result of decryption does not match the original value.

For example:

- 327: good decryption
- 512: problem with decryption

For encryption and decryption I use `BigInteger.ModPow()`.

```
using System;
using System.Numerics;

namespace ExperimentsWithCryptographicAlgorithms
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            BigInteger number = new BigInteger(327);

            KeyPair keys = new KeyPair();
            keys.OpenKey = new Key(new BigInteger(5), new BigInteger(493));
            keys.SecurityKey = new Key(new BigInteger(269), new BigInteger(493));

            BigInteger hash = Encrypt(number, keys.OpenKey);
            if (Decrypt(hash, keys.SecurityKey) == number)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Succesfully encrypted / decrypted!");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error in encryption or decryption!");
            }
        }

        static BigInteger Encrypt(BigInteger encryptedValue, Key publicKey)
        {
            return BigInteger.ModPow(encryptedValue, publicKey.FirstPart, publicKey.SecondPart);
        }

        static BigInteger Decrypt(BigInteger decryptedValue, Key securityKey)
        {
            return BigInteger.ModPow(decryptedValue, securityKey.FirstPart, securityKey.SecondPart);
        }
    }

    public struct Key
    {
        public BigInteger FirstPart { get; set; }
        public BigInteger SecondPart { get; set; }

        public Key(BigInteger fPart, BigInteger sPart)
        {
            FirstPart = fPart;
            SecondPart = sPart;
        }
    }

    public struct KeyPair
    {
        public Key OpenKey { get; set; }
        public Key SecurityKey { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you want to use encryption why not use the RSACryptoServiceProvider?

Comment: Thats for studying algorithms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked your algorithm and it works great for numbers in the range -492 to 492. It seems like a physical limitation of the algorithm, since the last arithmetic operation is a modulo with securityKey.SecondPart, which happens to be 493.

Comment: That is not fhysical limitation of RSA, because with other keys 512 correctly decrypted

Comment: KeyPair keys = new KeyPair();
keys.OpenKey = new Key(new BigInteger(17), new BigInteger(3233));
keys.SecurityKey = new Key(new BigInteger(2753), new BigInteger(3233));

Comment: I mean that the SecondPart of the security key imposes a limitation to the maximum number that can be encrypted and decrypted. You can't encrypt a number larger than the securityKey.SecondPart.

Comment: @SergeySulimov - look again at `ModPow`. Considering how it works, how can you expect it to return `512` when the third argument is `493`?